# Animate grid items to new position

Tags: jquery, css, insert, grid-layout

I have a set of floating items of equal size within a grid. 
Now I'm inserting another, bigger item via jquery .after(), which takes up the whole width of the container and therefore needs its own row.

The items that follow directly after the inserted item need to reposition and move to the next row.

I'd like to animate this movement.

Now I know there are a lot of plugins out there like isotope, mixitUp or masonry that do this sort of thing, but i feel like they would be overkill for something that 'simple'.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you won't be able to animate them how you want unless you have them absolutely positioned like isotope. A CSS transition wouldn't animate the box moving, everything would just snap down. And you wouldn't be able to do it with javascript unless you had specific units (something like top:100px;). I use isotope for http://invisiblesound.net and it works great, for the simplest implementation.

Comment: Yeah, i've used isotope before, liked it a lot but thought i could avoid it this time. Thank you for your advice, sounds plausible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate, with css or jQuery, the new box's width, having it slide from 0 to 100%. The smaller boxes wouldn't float to their respective places, they would be pushed to the right and then pop down to the next row, but it's easy and might work well enough.

Comment: The animation of the new box is no problem at all. The way you decribed is exactly what I've been doing so far. I was just looking to avoid that generic pop-down / jumping.

Comment: What if you animated the height, or used jQuery slideDown()? That wouldn't involve any popping.

Comment: I can push them down smoothly this way, but only once all the smaller boxes are in the next row below the new element. But to get to this new row, they still pop. I settled for using the isotope plugin which adds absolute positioning which seems to be the only way to animate them. Thank you for taking the time to reply again though.